# Odoo v11 Stock Movement - Configuring operation type doesn't work

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Create a new operation type to give default destination location different from Partner/Customers to some internal location

Create sale order --> Delivery --> Select the Operation type you created.

**Issue:**
The destination location we set in operation type is not changing. Always it is Partners/Customer

**Expectation**
The destination location should be fetched from the default location defined in Operation Type.

Any idea to create an operation type which suits our movement of stock?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo will take note of Operation types default location, if it don't find default location in Partner's record.

So that's expected. You may update your partner record and try it again. It will use Operation type default location.

If you want to do internal transfer location, you may have to create another picking with internal Operation type.